# Form submit on radio select

Tags: php, javascript

Quick question,

Is it possible to have a form submitted when a radio button is selected (without javascript)? Kind of like a quiz?

Essentially, I no longer want a 'submit' button. The user will input several fields, then choose a radio button to submit the form. Each radio button will have a value associated, which I will need to capture.

Ideas?

Comment: Make fake radio buttons that are actually submit buttons?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer you cannot do it unless you use javascript.

Crazy answer yes you can. You can create radio-buton-like-looking images and use them as submit buttons to submit different forms. So you would be submitting the form when the user clicks submit button which looks like a radio button.

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="">
<INPUT NAME="answer" value="answer is blue" TYPE="image" SRC="radio-button-image.jpg"> 
<INPUT NAME="answer" value="answer is red" TYPE="image" SRC="radio-button-image.jpg"> 
</FORM>
```

Comment: Thanks!

I am not against using different buttons to submit the form either, but how would I capture a value by doing that? 

For example, a user will input their name, then click on red, green, or blue... I still need to capture which color they clicked on - and I don't want to use a standard submit button, the last step will be them choosing an option.

Comment: You could add a name attribute to your radio-buton-like-looking-image-submit-button. You can have multiple ones, posting the same form with different name attributes which you can use to separate them between each other

Comment: I see, so there wouldn't be a value for the button itself, just a name?

Comment: Actually the easy way would be giving the same the to the buttons and giving different values, representing different radio-button-answers. See my example above.

Comment: I'm not sure if this works, when I print the result, it gives x & Y values.

Comment: I found a quick fix, I just gave them all different names, then checked if the x value was set, then reassigned what I needed after that. Still open to any other suggestions, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with javascript

```
<script>
    function submitOnClick(formName){
        document.forms[formName].submit();
    }
</script>
<form id="myForm" ...>
    <input type="radio" onclick="submitOnClick('myForm')>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with Ajax. You will need to provide a URL where you place a function `actionAsynchronous`. In this function you will be able to get the selected radio button by using the POST variable. Then you will be able to manage the selected radio button value. This works for me using Php and Yii Framework.